# I am driving my parents' home for ten hours these days

Tags: grammar, tense

I am driving my parents' home for ten hours these days.
Is this sentence correct & meaningful?
What I would like to write is I am driving  my parents' home very often these days.And when I calculate the total time taken by my frequent driving my parents' home is ten hours.

Comment: Ten hours in how long? In a day, a week, a month? We can't guess unless you tell us.

Comment: Do you mean 'driving _to_ my parents' home' (the apostrophe indicating 'the home of my parents') or 'driving my parents [to their] home'?

Comment: Short answer: NO, it's not "meaningful" (I might *guess* what you're trying to say, but I can't be sure my guess would be correct). The ***long answer*** (explaining what's wrong with it, and an example of how it ***should*** be phrased) can't be provided unless and until you provide some unambiguous (even if "ungrammatical") text that conveys the ***intended*** meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence, as constructed, is not sensible. What you have said is that you are driving a house for 10 hours. Since houses are not something one can drive, the statement can not be correctly interpreted, and the meaning must be guessed.

Possible meanings could include:

- I am driving my parents *to their* home, *and it takes me 10 hours to make that drive*.
- I am driving *to* my parents' home, *and it takes me 10 hours to make that drive*.

Even your clarification does not tell us whether you are going, yourself, alone, to your parents' house, or you are carrying your parents, in your car, to their house. Also, the period of time during which you total 10 hours of driving is unclear. It could be daily, or weekly, or monthly, or something else. My example sentences above assume that you are driving, at one go, for 10 hours, from your starting point, to reach your parents' house.

Also, using "these days" creates difficulties in understanding. "These days" is an indefinite period. So, adding up 10 hours in the time period "these days" makes little sense. It would communicate more clearly if you stated the time period over which it takes you 10 hours to do your driving. E.g.:

- 10 hours each way (10 out of 24)
- 10 hours round trip (5 hours each way)
- 10 hours a week
- 10 hours a month

Comment: While _houses_ usually can't be driven, many _homes_ (the word used by the OP) can: mobile homes, houseboats. The sentence isn't nonsensical or hopeless. It just doesn't mean what the OP surely intended! To the OP: this isn't just pedantry. The spurious apostrophe (possessive instead of plural) really did cause me to imagine a person driving a mobile home, and I had to read it again a couple of times to figure out what you meant!

Comment: @TypeIA You are quite correct. However, I felt that introducing RVs and mobile homes into the equation unduly complicated matters. Please also recall that, at least in American English, "mobile homes" are also not driven - they are hauled. However, an RV can be used as a home, and would be both mobile and driveable. Houseboats, in general, can be "driven", as watercraft - but houseboats are rare and exceptional in the US. I agree that this is not pedantry. I would hope that my answer did not indicate the sentence was nonsensical or hopeless. It just didn't make the sense the OP intended.